# PHP Template - Overwrite background-image location with PHP Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, image, dynamic, replace

my intention is to build a wordpress template file where specific images are overwritten with php by using a shortcode which appears inside the posts.

The scenario:
1) I use the sliderrevolution plugin and define the background image of a specific slider as placeholder.jpg
2) I put the shortcode into my page and when the specific file, in this case: placeholder.jpg is found it will be replaced by lets say: post-one.jpg.

My intention is to use the same slider within different posts and replace everything with shortcodes.

This works great with text, but I didn´t find a way to change the pictures dynamically. Of course the pictures have the same size as the ones I want to replace.

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks in advance.

I tried the code below, but I don´t get it to work. This is the HTML Code I want to "change".

EDIT:

Thanks for your fast answer ;) I tried using your code, but I don´t get it to work :(

This is the HTML Code of the Image I want to replace:

```
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 1; visibility: inherit; z-index: 20; background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/revslider/fashion/fashion_bg1.jpg&quot;); background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/revslider/fashion/fashion_bg1.jpg"></div></code>
```

I tried multiple codes as it didn´t change anything:

```
<script>
$("tp-bgimg defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$("tp-bgimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$("defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");

$("#tp-bgimg defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$("#tp-bgimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$("#defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");

$(".tp-bgimg defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$(".tp-bgimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");
$(".defaultimg").attr("src", "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/logo.png");

</script>
```

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong? The script is located in the header and is callable (used an alert to test).

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use jQuery to dynamically hide an existing element and then display something else in place of it.

A good example of this would be:

```
$("#img1").attr("src", "path/to/new_img.jpg");
```